# css menu drops down not at intended place

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I'm very new to making websites, mostly I do this as a hobby and now I'm working on a website for a friend of mine.

Everything went fine so far but I'm struggling with the menu. (It is also a wordpress website.)

You can preview it at http://www.decapeerwerken.be

The design is quite alright but the problem persists when you come underneath the dropdown menu. There is a sort of range where you can hover where it is not acceptable that the menu drops down, only when you hover on the parent link.

I can see myself that the height of ul.submenu is too high but I can't find it. Already been looking for days after this little issue...

Thank you guys in advance for helping me out!

CODE:

```
.menu {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FEF9CD, #FCE1BC);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#FEF9CD, #FCE1BC);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FEF9CD, #FCE1BC);
    background: linear-gradient(#FCE3BC, #FEF9CD, #FCE1BC);
    border: 1px solid #FCE1BC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #A4743d;
}
ul.nav-menu li a {
    color: #604443;
    font-family:'Oregano', cursive;
}
.nav-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav-menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.nav-menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-menu li:hover {
    color: #965A3E;
    transition: color 0.8s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    background: linear-gradient(#FCE3BC, #FFFCE3, #FCE1BC);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #A4743d;
    margin-top: -1px;
    background-position: 0 -40px;
}
.nav-menu li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav-menu li:hover ul {
    padding-top: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.8s;
}
.nav-menu li:hover ul li {
    float: none;
    position: static;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient(#FCE3BC, #FEF9CD, #FCE1BC);
    transition: background-color 1.4s, color 0.8s, box-shadow 0.5s;
    color: #965A3E;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that hover changes the layout (the contents occupy more space, even though they are hidden, when the parent is not hovered), but also that because you are only changing `opacity`, the user can still hover the contents when they are hidden.

I managed to fix the issue by transitioning `visibility` as well as `opacity`, which means you can no longer hover over the contents when they are invisible:

```
.nav-menu li ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav-menu li:hover ul {
    padding-top: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: opacity 0.8s, visibility 0.8s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace "opacity:1" (opacity:0) with "display:block;" ("display:none")

Comment: Thank You! I should buy you a beer!